# Implementing lists through functions

Tags: list, functional-programming, pseudocode

I implemented [lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_%28abstract_data_type%29) like this:

(pseudocode (or rather slightly changed Python))

```
function nil():
    function inner(index):
        return null          // saying that the head of an empty list is null
    return inner

function cons(list, element):
    function inner(index):
        if index = 0:
            return element
        else:
            return list(index-1)
    return inner

function head(list):
    return list(0)

function tail(list):
    function inner(index):
        return list(index+1)
return inner
```

And as a bonus:

```
function map(list, f):
    if head(list) is null:
        return list
    else:
        return cons(map(tail(list), f), f(head(list)))
```

However, this seems to be implementing lists as arrays (or hash tables) - an argument called `index` is used. However, I'd like to implement lists (using functions) without indices being used internally. Is this possible?

Comment: What are you talking about? There are no arrays or hash tables. If I stored the amount of apples I had in a variable and called that variable `index`, would you say apples are implemented using arrays? But yes, there are way of implementing lists using only functions, no numbers: Church encoding.

Comment: @delan That is the sense I meant it in - that the list function was indexed in order to get the head, rather than an index being defined as the head of a list after tail has been called on it so many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your representation is closest to a linked list, not to an array: you have to traverse through each element until you reach the one you want. You are only using `index` as a way of *addressing* the list.

To get a more "faithful" method of addressing, you could replace `inner` with `isnil`, `head` and `tail` operations, as per the [Church encoding of lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#List_encodings).